# SWRL rule if the condition is not specified

Tags: swrl

```
Person(?p),Age(?a), age(?p, ?a1), greaterThan(?a1, 18) -> Adult(?p)
```

but if persons  age  is not specified to give age not specified or specify age - please suggest swrl rule for this

I tried few arguments but not working

Comment: what? I mean, what would be the conclusion of the rule if the age is not specified?

Comment: absence of information is not something OWL resp. SWRL inference does take into account given that the Open World Assumption holds.

Comment: I also don't get why you make a class `Age` - what is the purpose of having such a class? And why then with a variable `?a` which is not connected to anything else in the rule?